# Firewall Activation Process

Tags: firewall

How do I activate my firewall through the terminal and is it Necessary or done automatic.

My regards team!

thmoabw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel in Ubuntu provides a packet filtering system called netfilter, and the traditional interface for manipulating netfilter are the iptables suite of commands. iptables provide a complete firewall solution that is both highly configurable and highly flexible.

Basic Usage

Getting started with ufw is easy. For example, to enable firewall, allow ssh access, enable logging, and check the status of the firewall, perform:

```
$ sudo ufw allow ssh/tcp
$ sudo ufw logging on
$ sudo ufw enable
$ sudo ufw status
Firewall loaded

To                         Action  From
--                         ------  ----
22:tcp                     ALLOW   Anywhere
```

This sets up a default deny (DROP) firewall for incoming connections, with all outbound connections allowed with state tracking.

source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall